# Android Material Design Progress bar внутри Button

Tags: android, button, material-design, progress-bar, android-material

На сайте material.io есть статья о [progress indicators](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html#circular-progress-indicators). Там есть совет как должна выглядеть реализация Integrating with actions (интеграциями с действиями) [mp4 видео с сайта material.io](https://material.io/design/assets/14AGELBP-uoljmxh5XYolF2_pfzXsoQPN/05-circular-placement-integrated-do.mp4).

Верно ли я понял, что они описали принципы, а реализацию не предоставили? Например для bottom navigation есть [принципы дизайна](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html), а так же [реализация компонента для Android](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/).

Как сделать подобную кнопку, с поддержкой Android API 4.4+.
Я не нашел простого решения, либо очень громозкий код, либо API 5.0+.

P.S. OpenSource библиотеки не рассматриваю, т.к. нужен не результат, а навыки и знания. Спасибо!

Comment: Android 5 -> API 21, Android 4.4 -> API 19 надо выбрать какую то одну [систему обозначений](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels) либо Android versions, либо API Level.  Такого компонента, как круговой прогрессбар в API Android нет, вам надо писать свой кастомный `View`. Если вам нужны навыки и знания, то рассматривание исходного кода готовых библиотек очень хороший способ их получить.

Comment: Конкретно на видео используется не настоящий прогрессбар, а простая анимация для фона кнопки с движением полоски по кругу, она будет крутиться, заполняясь и начиная снова пока ее не отменят, это хорошо видно на других видео. Поддержка анимаций для `View` с API 1, насколько я помню.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тут два варианта:
 1. Кастомная вьюха на основе Button. В нее добавишь прогресс бар. 
 2. Либо попроще: на кнопке прогресс бар с атрибутом VISIBILITY:VIEW_GONE.
 При клике убираешь надпись
 Делаешь бар видимым
 и т.д.
Для наложения вью можно заюзать, например realative layout

Comment: Но если знания и навыки, то тогда кастомная вьюха